# Suggestion for designing an Access DB to store chronological snapshots of Excel sheet with ~100 rows and ~100 columns?

Tags: database, excel, ms-access, migration

I'm an Excel user trying to solve this one problem, and the only efficient way I can think of is do it by a database. I use arrays in programming VBA/Python and I've queried from databases before, but never really designed a database. So I'm here to look for suggestion on how to structure this db in Access.

Anyway, I currently maintain a sheet of ~50 economics indicators for ~100 countries. It's a very straightforward sheet, with

Column headers: GDP , Unemployment , Interest Rate, ... ... ... Population

And Rows:

Argentina

Australia

...

...

Yemen

Zambia

etc.

I want to take snapshots of this sheet so I can see trends and run some analysis in the future. I thought of just keep duplicating the worksheet in Excel but it just feels inefficient.

I've never designed a database before.  My question would be what's the most efficient way to store these data for chronological snapshots? In the future I will probably do these things:

1. Queue up a snapshot for day mm-dd-yy in the past.
2. Take two different data point of a metric, of however many countries, and track the change/rate of change etc.
3. Once I can queue them well enough I'll probably do some kind of statistical analysis, which just requires getting the right data set.

I feel like I need to create an individual table for each country and add a row to every country table every time I take a snapshot. I'll try to play with VBA to automate this.

I can't think of any other way to do this with less tables? What would you suggest? Is it a recommended practice to use more than a dozen tables for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing this,
Option 1

Id suggest you probably only need a single table, something akin to,

Country, date_of_snapshot, columns 1-50 (GDP etc..)

Effective you would add a new row for each day and each country,

Option 2
You could also use a table atructured as below though this would require more complex queries which may be too much for access,

Country, datofsnapshot, factor, value

with each factor GDP etc... getting a row for each date and country

Comment: Do you think it's an overkill to maintain a table for individual countries then? I thought about your way in the beginning and I think it's the most straightforward way

Comment: Yeah, you'd probably be best with a single table with all the factors as columns, the only additional thing to worry about then would be the amount of data your going to hold. Thos would be down to the frequency of your snapahots and the amount of time you want to hold it for

Comment: Well I'm planning to make weekly snapshots for a long time. But I thought of trying to get older data and hopefully do some backtesting in the future. Is there a row count for a table by which Access gets cumbersome?

Comment: Im not sure on that one, it starts to spread to hardware, servers and such at that point. Though it wouldnt be hard to bulk load the system for ten yeara worth of data and test it

Comment: With an index on `date_of_snapshot`, you should be able to quickly retrieve the ~100 rows for one snapshot date even when the entire table contains *millions* of rows.

Comment: Even if you had daily data points for 200 countries, over 10 years it would come to 730,000 rows of data, really not that much for any kind of database. Assuming each column is mostly numbers and averages 16 bytes per column, we end up with a database of around 600MB. Again, far from the limits of Access. As long as you have the proper indexes in place, any query against this db would be very fast.